# how to convert string in array to html element

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, arrays, element

I want to render some data got from API response and as the code below ,temp array can show but list array can't.
[this picture link showes the render result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DP1kx.png)

Which I use push() can render sucessfully but which I use for loop to change value in array can't render sucessfully.

I want to know how to fix it, thanks a lot.

```
let list = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(responses))
for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < list[i].length; j++) {
    list[i][j] = `<li>${list[i][j]}</li>`
  }
}
```

```
let temp = []
for (let i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
  temp.push(
    <li className="ssl">
      <div className="box">
        <h3>{responses[i][0]}</h3>
          <ul className="ee">{list[i]}</ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  )
}
setResult(temp)
```

Comment: Why you need JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(responses)) this line ?

Comment: deep copy the responses from API , to prevent modify the origin data. Is that unnecessary?

Answer (score 2):

Just change the following

```
list[i][j] = `<li>${list[i][j]}</li>`
```

to

```
list[i][j] = <li>{list[i][j]}</li>
```

That's it.